# flask/jinja sending an array to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fullcalendar, jinja2

I have the following code in

> main.py:

```
@app.route("/admin")
def admin_panel():
    resources = [{'id': '302', 'title': 'Participant 302'}]
    events = []
    return render_template("admin.html", admin_resources=resources, admin_events=events)
```

In the corresponding html's head:

> admin.html

$(function() { // document ready

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  today: "12-18-18",
  editable: true, // enable draggable events
  aspectRatio: 1.8,
  scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
  header: {
    left: 'today,prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'timelineDay,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek'
  },
  defaultView: 'timelineThreeDays',
  resourceLabelText: 'Participants',

  resources: {{admin_resources}},
  events: {{ admin_events}}
});
```

});

I'm getting an exception because the quotation marks in the resources array is encoding. When I try {{admin_resources | tojson}} I get an error message stating that tojson returns None.

I'm stumped on how to solve this issue of quotes being encoded and why {{admin_resources | tojson}} is returning None.

Any thoughts? Thanks for any suggestions!

I'll note if I do {{admin_resources | safe}} the json seems correctly encoded; however, I get the following error even though I see the json array in the html:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resources' of undefined
    at t.n.Calendar.instantiateView (scheduler.min.js:8)
    at t.renderView (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
    at t.initialRender (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
    at t.render (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:11)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.i.fn.fullCalendar (fullcalendar.min.js:11)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (admin:29)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Why not feeding the `resources` and `events` vars from an async call from an API or web service ? isn't much easier ?

Comment: I was hoping jinja directly supports this feature. The async method seems like I'd need to mess with the calendar loading correctly.

Comment: Actually, after making changes to the edits, I'm wondering if the resources array is really an issue or not.

Comment: one solutions is using use restful API

Comment: Simplest solution is to use the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 changes that needed to be made:

1. today's date in the calendar cannot be "12-18-18". Needed to put into correct format: '2018-12-18'
2. Need to put the variable accesses using safe. {{admin_resources | safe}}